# How to substitute two lines in same text files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I need to substitute `backupconn1` with `maniconn` from connection text file, how can I make it specially from another script.

Below is connection.txt:

```
mainconn: 10.10.10.10
backupconn1:20.20.20.20
backupconn2:30.30.30.30
```

Comment: I need to substitute two lines in the same text file

Comment: please first start by showing your research. Check [ask] and [mcve].